# Notepad++ replace dots/punctuations that are alone not beeing surrounded by numbers

Tags: regex, notepad++

I would like to find dots/punctuations not surrounded by any numerics or alphanumerics (in other words surrounded by nothing) and replace these with nothing using Notepad++ and regex.

I tried using

```
(?<![a-zA-Z0-9]).(?![a-zA-Z0-9])
```

but it replaces all the numbers surrounding each dot with nothing.

How can this expression be adjusted appropiately for use in Notepad++ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape the `.` character:

```
(?<![a-zA-Z0-9])\.(?![a-zA-Z0-9])
```